# Booking plane ticket with EU, ID card or passport?

Tags: air-travel, eu, id

When flying to the EU from a non-EU country should I use for the booking my EU ID card or passport? Could there be a problem when checking in on the airport with EU ID card only? Example: Flying from Podgorica airport to Vienna airport and checking in only with EU ID card in Podgorica.

Comment: Which airline? In case it makes a difference to the answer

Comment: The US officially requires departing passengers to have a passport, though I've read one anecdote here in which an EU citizen who'd lost her passport while in the US (to theft, if I recall correctly) managed to board a flight home with her ID card.  Other countries might have similar provisions, but anyway it's generally possible to fly with documents you didn't provide at the time of booking.

Answer (score 2):

The booking is for the airways company. They just want some way to make sure who are you (in order to avoid you reselling the ticket, or that someone else tries to use your ticket without your permission).

They do not care at all which ID you use, as long it serves its purposes.

Passport controls (if any) will be made in a complete separate process.

Answer (score 2):

If a country is involved which does not accept the EU ID card, use your passport.

The airline may not mind but if they need to give API information it has to be a passport, and when they check your passport or ID card, it has to be valid for the border forces of both countries involved (although if there is no exit checks they might not note your passport number going out.)

It is true that the border checks are separate from buying your ticket, but the airline will need to check sometime you have the right paperwork, including visa if needed.

Comment: As far as the example is concerned, Montenegro and Austria both accept EU ID cards, though EU citizens using an ID instead of a passport can enter Montenegro only for 30 days instead of 90.